# Join two collections, taking the value from second collection (left outer join)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

Say I have two `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` a and b where a =

```
"one", "N",
"two", "N",
"three", "N"
```

and b =

```
"one", "Y"
"two", "N"
```

I want to do a left outer join, but take the value from b for the `Value` if there is an entry in b, so the result should be =

```
"one", "Y" <- this value is taken from b
"two", "N",
"three", "N"
```

I've tried doing a normal left outer join, but the result for the `Value` of "three" is always a blank string

```
    var res = (from l in a
              join r in b on l.Key equals r.Key into lrs
              from lr in lrs.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(l.Key, lr.Value)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work too:

```
var res = (from p in b.Concat(a)
           group p by p.Key into g
           select g.First()).ToArray();
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var res = b.Concat(a).GroupBy(p => p.Key, (k, g) => g.First()).ToArray();
```